# When I'm mounted, can I use the Bait and Switch maneuver exchanging the mount and my ally's position?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, fighter, mounted-combat

[Tasha's Cauldron of Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe) added one of my favourite maneuvers [Bait and Switch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/fighter#BaitandSwitch). In my game as a player I used it while mounted and the DM was like "Nice, like in chess [The king and rook maneuver]". Is it possible, rules as written, that me and my mount both change places with my ally?

> **Bait and Switch:** When you're with in 5 feet of a creature on your turn, you can expend one superiority die and switch places with that creature, provided you spend at least 5ft of movement and the creature is willing and isn't incapacitated. This movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks. (...)

Is it up to the DM? It doesn't specify.

Answer (score 5):

#### No. Your mount is not you.

Bait and Switch says:

> **you** can expend one superiority die and switch places with that creature, provided **you** spend at least 5ft of movement and the creature is willing and isn't incapacitated.

You are not your mount. Your mount does not go anywhere.

#### However, you can still switch places, but your ally probably isn’t mounted.

There’s nothing here that says you can’t do this while already mounted. It works, *but your ally doesn’t automatically mount your mount*. The rules for [mounting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountingandDismounting) say:

> Once during your move, you can mount a creature that is within 5 feet of you or dismount.

So your ally can only mount the mount during their move on their turn. It's going to be up to the DM to determine where the ally ends up relative to the mount, but the rules seem clear that "securely mounted" is not it.

Comment: but isn't "astride my horse" part of your place?  The fact that the mounting rules offer one (default) way to wind up astride a mount doesn't mean that that's the only way it can be done.

Comment: Right, but "mounted" is a clearly defined game term with clearly defined rules. "Astride" is not.

Comment: but "place" isn't a clearly defined game term either.  The question, then, is whether or not being mounted is part of "place".  I'd assert that it is, just by the general definition of the word.  "in the saddle on a horse" is a different place than "standing next to the horse".  That's especially the case because the horse is a large creature, the mounted medium character becomes part of their base, and that means that the mounted medium character isn't specifically in any particular grid square.

Comment: This almost feels sloppy, especially the second statement about your ally not mounting. Where would they be? Haphazardly standing/laying on the mount (which could be considered mounted, albeit not properly)? UNDER the mount? Next to the mount, but sharing the same space... if possible? It just feels strange. It would make more sense to either have the mount switch with you, or to have your ally be mounted afterwards. (None of this to say you're wrong, it just feels like an oversight)

Comment: @TheLittlePeace what is happening here is that there is no rule for what does happen, just a rule for what does NOT happen. Personally to avoid that complicated situation of a horse and another creature sharing a space I would just rule that it doesn't work at all when mounted, but the actual decision is up to the DM.

Comment: Is it possible to ready an action, so as to mount the mount after you get moved into the battle master's position?

Answer (score 0):

#### RAW, no

From [DnDBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountedCombat),

> While you’re mounted, you have two options. You can either control the mount or allow it to act independently. Intelligent creatures...act independently.

In this case, the end result is the same regardless of your mounting style.  If your mount is independent,

> [B]earing a rider puts no restrictions on the Actions the mount can take, and it moves and acts as it wishes,

but "Bait and Switch" is *your* maneuver, not your mount's.  An intelligent mount doesn't get your class features, and therefore can't swap with an ally.

If your mount isn't independent, it still can't swap with your ally, as it

> moves as you direct it, and it has only three action options: Dash, Disengage, and Dodge.

Comment: Roll20, while probably accurate in its copy of the official rules, is not an official source. It would be much better to link to/cite D&D Beyond as it *is* an official source. It looks like an edit was made to the original question clarifying the question in your first paragraph. And, as a general rule, if the original question isn't clear, you should ask for clarification rather than try and answer based on a shaky understanding of what is being asked ;-)